# Batch Windows Parameters

Tags: windows, batch-file

I've been doing a few batch files to practice and there is something I have difficulty understanding. Please keep in mind I am new to this, and that my code will probably not be correct or be the most efficient.

My question is, how to provide a message in case the user has not provided with the parameters to run the batch file (Or in case he uses more parameters than needed)

```
set argu=true

If %1 == PhoneFamily ( findstr /is "%2" PhoneFamily.txt ) 
If %1 == PhoneFriends ( findstr /is "%2" PhoneFriends.txt )
If %1 == PhoneWork  ( findstr /is "%2" PhoneWork.txt )

If not "%%1"=="PhoneFamily" If not "%%1"=="PhoneWork" If not    "%%1"=="PhoneFriends" set argu=false
If "%argu%"=="false" echo "Wrong Parameters, Please Try Again. The Files are PhoneFamily, PhoneWork, PhoneFriends. Only 2 Paramaters at a time."
```

This is the only way I could find to prompt some sort of "error" in case too little or too many parameters are given. But I would like to learn a better way, that separates these possibilities (one error for no parameters, and one for 3 or more parameters given.

Comment: Use `if "%~1"=="PhoneFamily" ( ... )`; plain `%1` fails if empty (no argument is delivered); `%%1` is simply wrong (expands to `%1` literally)...

Answer (score 0):

```
set argu=%1
if not defined argu echo No argument provided&pause&goto :eof
set argu=true
```

As an old assembler programmer, I use variables for temporary storage.

The `&` concatenates instructions - obviously, the `pause` is optional. the `goto :eof` where the `:` is compulsory in this case is an inbuilt function meaning "go to end of file"